# Why should i put service name after create in the providers array in app.module.ts?

Tags: angular

I am using as always ng g s [nameOfTheService] to generate a service.That makes the following service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {

  constructor() { }
}
```

this service can be accessed now through all components,but i saw one video where it is saying that we should specify the name of the service in the providers array in the app.module.ts file.
Why we should do that? I never did that and i never had problems with singleton dependency injection in angular.

Comment: in earlier versions of angular we needs to inject the service to modules to define its scope (if we inject in app module its accessible through out the application), but with latest versions of angular we have `providedIn` to define the scope of the service

Comment: @Edison Thank you for your answer .But what if i have some featured module and i specify the service in the provoders array in that featured module then how the things will work out ?

Answer (score 0):

The injector is responsible for creating service instances and injecting them into classes.

Should, for example, the service live once inside the app or module? Or should every component that depends on the service have its own instance?

Depending on the context, you might have to set metadata inside the `@NgModule()` decorator.

From the [docs](http://You%20can%20configure%20injectors%20with%20providers%20at%20different%20levels%20of%20your%20app,%20by%20setting%20a%20metadata%20value%20in%20one%20of%20three%20places:%20%20In%20the%20@Injectable()%20decorator%20for%20the%20service%20itself.%20%20In%20the%20@NgModule()%20decorator%20for%20an%20NgModule.%20%20In%20the%20@Component()%20decorator%20for%20a%20component.%20%20The%20@Injectable()%20decorator%20has%20the%20providedIn%20metadata%20option,%20where%20you%20can%20specify%20the%20provider%20of%20the%20decorated%20service%20class%20with%20the%20root%20injector,%20or%20with%20the%20injector%20for%20a%20specific%20NgModule.%20%20The%20@NgModule()%20and%20@Component()%20decorators%20have%20the%20providers%20metadata%20option,%20where%20you%20can%20configure%20providers%20for%20NgModule-level%20or%20component-level%20injectors.):

> You can configure injectors with providers at different levels of your app, by setting a metadata value in one of three places:
>
> In the @Injectable() decorator for the service itself.
>
> In the @NgModule() decorator for an NgModule.
>
> In the @Component() decorator for a component.
>
> The @Injectable() decorator has the providedIn metadata option, where you can specify the provider of the decorated service class with the root injector, or with the injector for a specific NgModule.
>
> The @NgModule() and @Component() decorators have the providers metadata option, where you can configure providers for NgModule-level or component-level injectors.